# Finding values of x for a given y when approaching a limit

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to find two x values for each y value on a plot that is very similar to a Gaussian fn. The difficulty is that I need to be able to find the values of x for several values of y even when the gaussian fn is very close to zero.

I can't post an image due to being a new user, however think of a gaussian function and then the regions where it is close to zero on either side of the peak. This part where the fn is very close to reaching zero is where I need to find the x values for a given y.

What I've tried:
When the fn is discrete: I have tried interp1, however I get the error that it is not strictly monotonic increasing because of the many values that are close to zero.

When I fit a two-term gaussian:
I use fzero (fzero(function-yvalue)) however I get a lot of NaN's. These might be from me not having a close enough 'guess' value??

Does anyone have any other suggestions for me to try? Or how to improve what I've already attempted?

Thanks everyone

[image]

EDIT:
I've added a picture below. The data that I actually have is the blue line, while the fitted eqn is in red. The eqn should be accurate enough.
Again, I'm trying to pick out x values for a given y where y is very small (approaching 0).

I've tried splitting the function into left and right halves for the interpolation and fzero method.

Thanks for your responses anyway, I'll have a look at bisection.

Comment: Upload your image to a public sharing website, post a link in your post and I will update your post with the image embedded in.  It's very difficult to visualize this without an image.   Also, please add any code you have used to try and solve your problem.  The answer may be a simple modification to what you have done, which is probably the ideal case and the easiest.

Comment: Is the image the only form in which you have the data? If not, just post the data themselves, maybe a downsampled version to save space.

Comment: And, are you sure the problem that its not increasing is because of the close-to-zero numbers? If your function goes up to a maximum and then down again, you have a much stronger nonmonotonicity. That's the first thing I'd try to get rid of, by splitting the function into the increasing and the decreasing part.

Answer (score 0):

Fitting a Gaussian seems to be uneffective, as its deviation (in the x-coordinate) from the real data is noticeable.

Since your data is already presented as a numeric vector y, the straightforward `find(y<y0)` seems adequate. Here is a sample code, in which the y-values are produced from a perturbed  Gaussian.

```
x = 0:1:700;
y = 2000*exp(-((x-200)/50).^2 - sin(x/100).^2);     %  imitated data
plot(x,y)                

y0 = 1e-2;                                          % the y-value to look for

i = min(find(y>y0));                                % first entry above y0
if i == 1             
    x1 = x(i);
else
    x1 = x(i) - y(i)*(x(i)-x(i-1))/(y(i)-y(i-1));   % linear interpolation
end

i = max(find(y>y0));                                % last entry above y0 
if i == numel(y) 
    x2 = x(i);
else
    x2 = x(i) - y(i)*(x(i)-x(i+1))/(y(i)-y(i+1));   % linear interpolation
end

fprintf('Roots: %g, %g \n', x1, x2)
```

Output: `Roots: 18.0659, 379.306`

The curve looks much like your plot.

[image: data]